# How do you put document id into object?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My current code is like this.
I got some documents from items collection.

```js
querySnapshot = db.itemsCollection.get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id);
  console.log(doc.data());
});


1
Object {
  "name": "first",
  "uid": 1,
}
2
Object {
  "name": "second",
  "uid": 2,
}
```

I could get document's id and object but I wanna put document id into object.
I wanna make object like

```js
Object {
  "id" : 1,
  "name": "first",
  "uid": 1,
}
Object {
  "id" : 2,
  "name": "second",
  "uid": 2,
}
```

How can I do this?
I would appreciate it if you could give me some advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
querySnapshot = db.itemsCollection.get();
const newQuerySnapshpt = querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
    return {
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
    }
});
console.log(newQuerySnapshot);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would map over the documents and use the spread operator to achieve this.

```js
let objects = querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
  return {
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data()
  }
});
```